# SQL Server stored procedure not updating table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Currently I have a stored procedure a.k.a a main entrance procedure that processes as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [JDSports].[SYC_LoopTemp_0All]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @rundate as datetime
    SET @rundate = getdate()

    INSERT INTO RecordTime (record_date) 
        (SELECT @rundate)

    EXEC  SYC_LoopTemp_1New;

    UPDATE recordtime 
    SET _1New = 1 
    WHERE record_date = @rundate;

    EXEC SYC_LoopTemp_2Normal;

    UPDATE recordtime 
    SET _2Normal = 1 
    WHERE record_date = @rundate;

    EXEC SYC_LoopTemp_3Reprint;

    UPDATE recordtime 
    SET _3Reprint = 1 
    WHERE record_date = @rundate;

    EXEC SYC_LoopTemp_4Error;

    UPDATE recordtime 
    SET _4Error = 1 
    WHERE record_date = @rundate;
END
```

What I am currently faced is that after the procedures have been run successfully, the record_date table now shows the value of columns `_1New` to `_4Error` (these four columns are of `smallint` datatype) as null, whereas if I run the update command as a single solitary SQL statement, it is able to be updated. The funny thing is that a few days prior to this incident happening, the values in a record properly shows the value 1 on the four columns.

I've checked the other four stored procedures and it was running correctly, that is no errors were shown when they were running.

Is there any part of the procedure or the target table that is at fault or could this be due to the BCP process hasn't been completed in full?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
Yes, the procedures are run via BCP. I also run by SSMS if I want to just run one of the 4 inner procedures.

SYC_LoopTemp_1New: Inserts new customers, cashiers, items and sales etc into their respective tables. Existing ones will not be added as it is redundant.

```
 INSERT INTO customer (name) (
        SELECT DISTINCT customer_desc FROM temp_receipt WHERE customer_desc NOT IN 
        (select name from customer)
        );

        INSERT INTO salesPerson (name) (
            SELECT DISTINCT salesPerson_desc FROM temp_purchase WHERE salesPerson_desc NOT IN 
            (select name from salesPerson)
        );

        INSERT INTO discRef ([desc]) (
            SELECT DISTINCT discRef FROM temp_purchase WHERE discRef NOT IN 
            (select [desc] from discRef)
        );

        INSERT INTO outlet (id, [desc]) (
        SELECT DISTINCT outlet_desc, outlet_desc FROM temp_receipt WHERE outlet_desc NOT IN 
        (select id from outlet)
        );

        INSERT INTO pos ([desc], outlet_id) (
        SELECT DISTINCT pos_desc, outlet_desc FROM temp_receipt WHERE temp_receipt.pos_desc NOT IN 
        (select [desc] from pos)
        );

        INSERT INTO cashier (name) (
        SELECT DISTINCT cashier_desc FROM temp_receipt WHERE temp_receipt.cashier_desc NOT IN 
        (select name from cashier)
        );

        INSERT INTO item_barcode ([desc]) (
        SELECT item_desc FROM temp_purchase WHERE temp_purchase.item_desc NOT IN 
        (select [desc] from item_barcode) GROUP BY item_desc
        );
```

SYC_LoopTemp_2Normal: Inserts records extracted from the temporary purchase and receipt tables into the normal receipt and purchase tables. Duplicated / defective records will be not be extracted here but to another pair of tables.

```
select * into #receipt_normal from  receipt where 1 = 0 ;

    INSERT INTO #receipt_normal ([fileName], [pos_id],[recpt_id],[RefNo],[recpt_dt],[cashier_id],[customer_id],[customer_count],[total_sales],
               [cash_paid],[cash_change],[master_paid], [visa_paid], [debit_paid],[amex_paid],[TaxStdRate],[TaxStdTotal],[TaxStdAmnt],[refund], [ascii], [recpt_png])
    (
        SELECT t.[fileName], p.id, t.recpt_id, t.RefNo, t.recpt_dt, cashier.id, customer.id, t.customer_count, t.total_sales, 
            t.cash_paid, t.cash_change, t.master_paid, t.visa_paid, t.debit_paid, t.amex_paid, t.TaxStdRate, t.TaxStdTotal, t.TaxStdAmnt, t.refund, t.[ascii], t.[recpt_png]
        FROM ( SELECT * FROM temp_receipt where [fileName] in (
          select max([fileName]) from temp_receipt
          GROUP BY pos_desc,recpt_id, refund 
          HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 )) t, pos p, cashier, customer
        WHERE t.pos_desc = p.[desc] 
        AND t.cashier_desc = cashier.[name]
        AND t.customer_desc = customer.[name]
        AND ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM receipt r, pos p
            WHERE r.[pos_id] = p.[id]
            AND p.[desc] = t.[pos_desc]
            AND r.[recpt_id] = t.[recpt_id]
            AND r.[refund] = t.[refund] ) = 0
    );

    DELETE FROM temp_receipt 
    WHERE [filename] IN ( SELECT [filename] FROM #receipt_normal);

    INSERT INTO receipt SELECT * FROM #receipt_normal;

    INSERT INTO purchase ([pos_id],[recpt_id],[salesPerson_id],[item_id],[count],[discount],[discRef_id],[fileName],[amount],[TaxCategory])
    (
        SELECT p.id, t.recpt_id, salesPerson.[id], bc.barcode, t.[count], t.[discount], discRef.[id], t.[fileName], t.[amount], t.TaxCategory
        FROM temp_purchase t, item_barcode bc, pos p, salesPerson, discRef
        WHERE t.item_desc = bc.[desc] 
        AND t.pos_desc = p.[desc] 
        AND t.salesPerson_desc = salesPerson.[name] 
        AND t.discRef = discRef.[desc] 
        AND t.fileName IN (SELECT fileName FROM #receipt_normal)
    );

    DELETE FROM temp_purchase
    WHERE [filename] IN (SELECT [filename] FROM #receipt_normal);

    DROP TABLE #receipt_normal;
```

SYC_LoopTemp_03Reprint: Extracts records that have been flagged as reprinted or duplicated in the temporary purchase and receipt table, then put them into the group of duplicate purchase / receipt tables

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @_rcp_count INT;
    DECLARE @_rcp_loop INT;
    DECLARE @_pos_desc VARCHAR(max);
    DECLARE @_recpt_id VARCHAR(max);
    DECLARE @_refund INT;
    DECLARE @_sum_rows INT;
    DECLARE @_reprint_loop INT;

    DECLARE @_insert_fileName VARCHAR(max);
    DECLARE @_exist_fileName INT;
    DECLARE @_exist_total INT;
    DECLARE @_exist_purchase INT;
    DECLARE @_compare_total INT;
    DECLARE @_compare_purchase INT;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS uniqueRcp;
    CREATE TABLE uniqueRcp (
        [pos_desc] varchar(64) NOT NULL,
        [recpt_id] varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        [refund] smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        PRIMARY KEY ([pos_desc],[recpt_id], [refund])
    );

    INSERT INTO uniqueRcp ([pos_desc],[recpt_id], [refund])
    (SELECT DISTINCT [pos_desc],[recpt_id], [refund] FROM temp_receipt);

    SET @_rcp_loop = 0;
    SELECT @_rcp_count = COUNT(*) FROM uniqueRcp;
    WHILE @_rcp_loop < @_rcp_count 
    BEGIN
        SELECT top 1 @_pos_desc = [pos_desc], @_recpt_id = [recpt_id], @_refund = [refund] 
        FROM uniqueRcp;

        DELETE TOP(1) FROM uniqueRcp;

        SELECT @_sum_rows = COUNT(*) FROM temp_receipt
            WHERE [pos_desc] = @_pos_desc
            AND [recpt_id] = @_recpt_id
            AND [refund] = @_refund;

        SET @_reprint_loop = 0;

        IF ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM receipt r, pos p
            WHERE r.[pos_id] = p.[id]
            AND p.[desc] = @_pos_desc
            AND r.[recpt_id] = @_recpt_id
            AND r.[refund] = @_refund ) > 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @_exist_total = max(r.total_sales), @_exist_purchase = COUNT(*)
            FROM receipt r, purchase b, pos p
            WHERE r.[fileName] = b.[fileName]
            AND r.[pos_id] = p.[id]
            AND p.[desc] = @_pos_desc
            AND r.[recpt_id] = @_recpt_id
            AND r.[refund] = @_refund
            GROUP BY r.[fileName];
        END 
        ELSE BEGIN
            SELECT top 1 @_insert_fileName = r.[fileName], @_exist_total = max(r.total_sales), @_exist_purchase = COUNT(*)
            FROM temp_receipt r, temp_purchase b
            WHERE r.[fileName] = b.[fileName]
            AND r.[pos_desc] = @_pos_desc
            AND r.[recpt_id] = @_recpt_id
            AND r.[refund] = @_refund
            GROUP BY r.[fileName]
            ORDER BY r.[fileName];
            /*ORDER BY r.recpt_dt; */

            SET @_reprint_loop = @_reprint_loop + 1;

            INSERT INTO receipt ([fileName], [pos_id],[recpt_id],[RefNo],[recpt_dt],[cashier_id],[customer_id],[customer_count],[total_sales],
            [cash_paid],[cash_change],[master_paid], [visa_paid], [debit_paid],[amex_paid],[TaxStdRate],[TaxStdTotal],[TaxStdAmnt],[refund], [ascii], [recpt_png])
            (
                SELECT t.[fileName], p.id, t.recpt_id, t.RefNo, t.recpt_dt, cashier.id, customer.id, t.customer_count, t.total_sales, 
                t.cash_paid, t.cash_change, t.master_paid, t.visa_paid, t.debit_paid, t.amex_paid, t.TaxStdRate, t.TaxStdTotal, t.TaxStdAmnt, t.refund, t.[ascii], t.[recpt_png]
                FROM temp_receipt t, pos p, cashier, customer
                WHERE t.pos_desc = p.[desc] 
                AND t.cashier_desc = cashier.[name]
                AND t.customer_desc = customer.[name]
                AND t.[fileName] = @_insert_fileName
            );
            INSERT INTO purchase ([pos_id],[recpt_id],[salesPerson_id],[item_id],[count],[discount],[discRef_id],[fileName],[amount],[TaxCategory])
            (
                SELECT p.id, t.recpt_id, salesPerson.[id], bc.barcode, t.[count], t.discount, discRef.[id], t.[fileName], t.[amount], t.TaxCategory
                FROM temp_purchase t, item_barcode bc, pos p, salesPerson, discRef
                WHERE t.item_desc = bc.[desc] 
                AND t.pos_desc = p.[desc] 
                AND t.salesPerson_desc = salesPerson.[name] 
                AND t.discRef = discRef.[desc] 
                AND t.[fileName] = @_insert_fileName
            );
            DELETE FROM temp_receipt
            WHERE [fileName] = @_insert_fileName;
            DELETE FROM temp_purchase
            WHERE [fileName] = @_insert_fileName;
        END;

        WHILE @_reprint_loop < @_sum_rows 
        BEGIN
            SELECT top 1 @_insert_fileName = r.[fileName], @_compare_total = max(r.total_sales), @_compare_purchase = COUNT(*)
            FROM temp_receipt r, temp_purchase b
            WHERE r.[fileName] = b.[fileName]
            AND r.[pos_desc] = @_pos_desc
            AND r.[recpt_id] = @_recpt_id
            AND r.[refund] = @_refund
            GROUP BY r.[fileName]
            ORDER BY r.[fileName];
            /*ORDER BY r.recpt_dt; */


            IF ( @_exist_total = @_compare_total AND @_exist_purchase = @_compare_purchase )
            BEGIN
                SELECT @_exist_fileName = COUNT(*)
                FROM dup_receipt_reprint
                WHERE [fileName] = @_insert_fileName;

                IF ( @_exist_fileName = 0 )
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dup_receipt_reprint ([fileName], [pos_id],[recpt_id],[RefNo],[recpt_dt],[cashier_id],[customer_id],[customer_count],[total_sales],
                    [cash_paid],[cash_change],[master_paid], [visa_paid], [debit_paid],[amex_paid],[TaxStdRate],[TaxStdTotal],[TaxStdAmnt],[refund], [ascii], [recpt_png])
                    (
                        SELECT t.[fileName], p.id, t.recpt_id, t.RefNo, t.recpt_dt, cashier.id, customer.id, t.customer_count, t.total_sales, 
                        t.cash_paid, t.cash_change, t.master_paid, t.visa_paid, t.debit_paid, t.amex_paid, t.TaxStdRate, t.TaxStdTotal, t.TaxStdAmnt, t.refund, t.[ascii], t.[recpt_png]
                        FROM temp_receipt t, pos p, cashier, customer
                        WHERE t.pos_desc = p.[desc] 
                        AND t.cashier_desc = cashier.[name]
                        AND t.customer_desc = customer.[name]
                        AND t.[fileName] = @_insert_fileName
                    );
                    INSERT INTO dup_purchase_reprint ([pos_id],[recpt_id],[salesPerson_id],[item_id],[count],[discount],[discRef_id],[fileName],[amount],[TaxCategory])
                    (
                        SELECT p.id, t.recpt_id, salesPerson.id, bc.barcode, t.[count], t.discount, discRef.id, t.[fileName], t.amount, t.TaxCategory
                        FROM temp_purchase t, item_barcode bc, pos p, salesPerson, discRef
                        WHERE t.item_desc = bc.[desc] 
                        AND t.pos_desc = p.[desc] 
                        AND t.salesPerson_desc = salesPerson.[name] 
                        AND t.discRef = discRef.[desc] 
                        AND t.[fileName] = @_insert_fileName
                    );
                END 

                DELETE FROM temp_receipt WHERE fileName = @_insert_fileName;
                DELETE FROM temp_purchase WHERE fileName = @_insert_fileName;
            END
            ELSE BEGIN
                    SELECT @_exist_fileName = COUNT(*)
                    FROM dup_receipt_different
                    WHERE [fileName] = @_insert_fileName;

                IF ( @_exist_fileName = 0 )
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO dup_receipt_different ([fileName], [pos_id],[recpt_id],[RefNo],[recpt_dt],[cashier_id],[customer_id],[customer_count],[total_sales],
                        [cash_paid],[cash_change],[master_paid], [visa_paid], [debit_paid],[amex_paid],[TaxStdRate],[TaxStdTotal],[TaxStdAmnt],[refund], [ascii], [recpt_png])
                    (SELECT t.[fileName], p.id, t.recpt_id, t.RefNo, t.recpt_dt, cashier.id, customer.id, t.customer_count, t.total_sales, 
                            t.cash_paid, t.cash_change, t.master_paid, t.visa_paid, t.debit_paid, t.amex_paid, t.TaxStdRate, t.TaxStdTotal, t.TaxStdAmnt, t.refund, t.[ascii], t.[recpt_png]
                            FROM temp_receipt t, pos p, cashier, customer
                            WHERE t.pos_desc = p.[desc] 
                            AND t.cashier_desc = cashier.[name]
                            AND t.customer_desc = customer.[name]
                            AND t.fileName = @_insert_fileName
                    );
                    INSERT INTO dup_purchase_different ([pos_id],[recpt_id],[salesPerson_id],[item_id],[count],[discount],[discRef_id],[fileName],[amount],[TaxCategory])
                    (
                        SELECT p.id, t.recpt_id, salesPerson.[id], bc.barcode, t.[count], t.discount, discRef.[id], t.[fileName], t.[amount], t.TaxCategory
                                FROM temp_purchase t, item_barcode bc, pos p, salesPerson, discRef
                                WHERE t.item_desc = bc.[desc] 
                                AND t.pos_desc = p.[desc] 
                                AND t.salesPerson_desc = salesPerson.[name] 
                                AND t.discRef = discRef.[desc] 
                                AND t.fileName = @_insert_fileName
                    );
                END 

                DELETE FROM temp_receipt WHERE fileName = @_insert_fileName;
                DELETE FROM temp_purchase WHERE fileName = @_insert_fileName;
            END 
            SET @_reprint_loop = @_reprint_loop + 1;
        END;
        SET @_rcp_loop = @_rcp_loop + 1;
    END;
END
```

SYC_LoopTemp_4Error: Extracts erroneous records that have been flagged temporary purchase and receipt table, then put them into the group of error purchase / receipt tables.

```
INSERT INTO dup_receipt_error ([fileName], pos_id,recpt_id,RefNo,recpt_dt,cashier_id,customer_id,customer_count,total_sales,
    cash_paid,cash_change,master_paid, visa_paid, debit_paid,amex_paid,TaxStdRate,TaxStdTotal,TaxStdAmnt,refund, [ascii], recpt_png)
    (
        SELECT t.[fileName], p.id, t.recpt_id, t.RefNo, t.recpt_dt, cashier.id, customer.id, t.customer_count, t.total_sales, 
      t.cash_paid, t.cash_change, t.master_paid, t.visa_paid, t.debit_paid, t.amex_paid, t.TaxStdRate, t.TaxStdTotal, t.TaxStdAmnt, t.refund, t.[ascii], t.recpt_png
        FROM temp_receipt t, pos p, cashier, customer
    WHERE t.pos_desc = p.[desc] 
    AND t.cashier_desc = cashier.[name]
    AND t.customer_desc = customer.[name]
    );

    INSERT INTO dup_purchase_error (pos_id,recpt_id,salesPerson_id,item_id,[count],discount,discRef_id,[fileName],amount,TaxCategory)
    (
        SELECT p.id, t.recpt_id, salesPerson.id, bc.barcode, t.[count], t.discount, discRef.id, t.fileName, t.amount, t.TaxCategory
    FROM temp_purchase t, item_barcode bc, pos p, salesPerson, discRef
    WHERE t.item_desc = bc.[desc] 
    AND t.pos_desc = p.[desc] 
    AND t.salesPerson_desc = salesPerson.[name] 
    AND t.discRef = discRef.[desc] 
        AND t.[fileName] IN ( SELECT [fileName] FROM temp_receipt )
    );  

    TRUNCATE table temp_receipt;
    DELETE FROM temp_purchase
    WHERE [fileName] IN (SELECT [fileName] FROM dup_receipt_error);

    INSERT INTO dup_purchase_leftover (pos_id,recpt_id,salesPerson_id,item_id,[count],discount,discRef_id,[fileName],amount,TaxCategory)
    (
        SELECT p.id, t.recpt_id, salesPerson.id, bc.barcode, t.[count], t.discount, discRef.id, t.fileName, t.amount, t.TaxCategory
    FROM temp_purchase t, item_barcode bc, pos p, salesPerson, discRef
    WHERE t.item_desc = bc.[desc]
    AND t.pos_desc = p.[desc] 
    AND t.salesPerson_desc = salesPerson.[name]
    AND t.discRef = discRef.[desc] 
    );

    TRUNCATE table temp_purchase;
```

Arranging by descending order for the record_time table;

```
date    _1New   _2Normal    _3Reprint   _4error
------------------------------------------------
2018-06-06 12:57:54 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2018-06-06 12:56:44 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2018-06-06 12:55:44 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2018-05-29 11:52:40 1   1   1   1
2018-05-29 11:46:12 1   1   1   1
2018-05-29 11:43:52 1   1   1   1
2018-05-29 11:43:26 1   1   1   1
2018-05-29 11:40:56 1   1   1   1
2018-05-29 10:55:05 1   1   1   1
```

Comment: how do you execute the stored procedure? Via SQL Agent jobs, manually via SSMS, application code ?

Comment: There is no way to answer this without a lot more detail here. We would need to see the code in those procedures and the tables involved. To say this shooting blind at this point is a huge understatement.

Comment: Is there an error in the first step that aborts the stored procedure and leaves the columns NULL?  Do you have a table named `recordtime` in multiple schemas, and the stored procedure is updating the table in the other schema?

Comment: What does the procs `SYC_LoopTemp_xxx` do? And I agree with the comments above of wanting to see schema for the table etc.

Comment: Yes, this is run mainly by BCP. SSMS is run manually if I need to run either one of the four inner stored procs manually.

I've updated the question with the additional code that is being called.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I need to declare the @rundate scalar variable as datetime2.
Next, for the where condition, I will need to do some conversion. So the revised procedure was as follows:

```
   execute SYC_LoopTemp_1New;
    UPDATE _SYC_LoopTemp_State SET _1New = 1 WHERE [date] = CONVERT([datetime2](3), @runDate);
    execute SYC_LoopTemp_2Normal;
    UPDATE _SYC_LoopTemp_State SET _2Normal = 1 WHERE [date] = CONVERT([datetime2](3), @runDate);
    execute SYC_LoopTemp_3Reprint;
    UPDATE _SYC_LoopTemp_State SET _3Reprint = 1 WHERE [date] = CONVERT([datetime2](3), @runDate);
    execute SYC_LoopTemp_4error;
    UPDATE _SYC_LoopTemp_State SET _4error = 1 WHERE [date] = CONVERT([datetime2](3), @runDate);
```